# Spark RDD isEmpty method throws NullPointerException, when RDD is not null

Tags: apache-spark, nullpointerexception, rdd, is-empty

This took me by surprise (while explaining to someone, unfortunately).

I am curious about what happens internally in spark in the following snippet.

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(null)
rdd == null //false
rdd.isEmpty //NullPointerException
```

Before you ask, I agree parallelizing null is arguable, but this is simply a condition we run into in our streaming application.

I read somewhere that 'isEmpty' goes in and internally calls `rdd.take(1)`, which ultimately throws the exception, but this seems inconsistent with language behavior. Also, I found that in some cases it takes longer (few seconds sometimes) to return with an NPE, although that could be because it goes over the network looking for data.

So the question is, why does this happen? Is this expected behavior? Is there a better way to deal with this than caching NPE?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`parallelize` method expects a `Seq[T]`. While `null` is a valid substitution `NullPointerException` is to be expected whenever it is accessed as a `Seq` and it is no equivalent to an empty `Seq`.

Either use `SparkContext.emptyRDD`:

```
sc.emptyRDD[T]
```

or emtpy seq

```
sc.parallelize(Seq.emtpy[T])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that!
Problem is, we're not producing these RDDs manually, so we don't have control over whether to push an `SparkContext.emptyRDD` or null. We use Kafka to generate RDDs, so `KafkaReciever` does what it does. Would it be right to say then that this `KafkaReciever` is returning null instead of an empty Seq? Is that a known behavior?